# How to change keyboard layout to Belgian(Dutch) or Belgian(French) in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, keyboard-layout

I'm a bit confused by all these settings in <kbd>System Settings</kbd>→<kbd>Text Entry</kbd>：

- Belgian,Belgian (alternative),
- Belgian (alternative, latin-9 only),
- Belgian (alternative, Sun dead keys),
- Belgian (eliminate dead keys),
- Belgian (ISO alternate),
- Belgian (Sun dead keys),
- Belgian (Wang model 724 azerty)

and languages:

- Dutch, Dutch (Macintosh)
- Dutch (standard)
- Dutch (Sun dead keys)
- French, French (alternative)
- French (alternative, eliminate dead keys)
- French (alternative, latin-9 only)
- French (alternative, Sun dead keys)
- French (Switzerland, Sun dead keys)

*How can I set the keyboard layout settings to Belgian in Ubuntu 14.04?*

Comment: De rien! Graag gedaan! Bitte!  **;-)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ubuntu, language support is separated from the keyboard layout.  So you can install a full English environment while still using a Belgian keyboard. (which is the way I'm running)

So if you just want to have this keyboard layout:

[image: BE Keyboard layout]

1. Go to the gears icon in the top right of your screen:

   [image: Gears]
2. Click <kbd>System Settings</kbd>→<kbd>Text Entry</kbd>.
3. If your `Input Sources to use` contains anything else then "Belgian", remove them.
4. Add "Belgian" and make it top of the list.

#### Done!

If you also want to change the language of your UI to Dutch, French *or German*, go to <kbd>Language Support</kbd> in the System Settings...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Fabby for your answer.
To be more specific (in case others will face the same situation/configuration), on my Ubuntu (20.04.2 LTS) I do this:

- go to 'System settings / Region & Language'
- click the '+' symbol
- under 'Input Sources' click 'More' (3 dots symbol) enter 'French'
- click the 'French' result
  => only from there the 'Belgian' options are displayed - and this is why I wanted to add this precision.

Answer (score 0):

Same applies for Ubuntu 22.04... but you have to go to 'System setting / Keyboard'. Below "Input Source", click on the "+" symbol, and then click on the '3 vertical dots'. Type "Bel" on the search field. In my case the search returned "Dutch". Click on it and then you have all keyboards you like.