# Cannot find my keyboard layout

Tags: 18.04, keyboard-layout

I'm in Belgium (french part) and I cannot find the proper keyboard layout in Settings > Region and Languages > Input Sources. 
the closest I found is the french (AZERTY) one but for the symbols such as ! and _ it's not the same keys... 
what can I do to solve it ? 
Thank you.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/728998/how-to-change-keyboard-layout-to-belgiandutch-or-belgianfrench-in-ubuntu-14

Comment: So, basically, you're doing it wrong by selection French instead of Belgium. Both AZERTY but have slight differences. Keyboard layouts are usually by country, not by language.

Comment: Thanks but my version of ubuntu is 18.04 not 14.04

Comment: I can't find french(belgium) in the list

Comment: Again, you should be looking for BELGIUM, not French. And the version of Ubuntu doesn't matter. It was always like this.

Comment: Sorry, I missread

Comment: No input source found when I type Belgium ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have hit [this issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-control-center/issues/82). In that case you can generate a Belgian locale, e.g.:

```
sudo locale-gen fr_BE.UTF-8
```

Then you should be able to click French and find some Belgian layout options in the sub menu which opens.

Comment: thank you so so so much !!! It does the trick :D